# Comparing Two PDFs, Outputting the highlighted differences back in the same pdf

Tags: c#, python-2.7, pdf, highlight

I was able to extract the text  from ghost script and was able to compare phrases of text at a time. However the problem was the ghost script output the text in a funky way. I was looking to compare elements by elements (Tables,Text,Images).I am looking to come up with an automated solution to do this. Im looking in to Itextsharp  but couldn't find any documentations.

My biggest challenge is iterating through elements and comparing them with in the two PDFs.

Can anyone assist ?

Comment: diffing files is extremely complex. I suggest you look for a 3rd party library.

Comment: are you looking for the solution with c# or python?

Comment: Iam looking for a solution with either one. I spend days trying different libraries and still no luck. most of them are paid. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be

- use [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) to extract images and text separately
- compare text using [google-diff-match-patch](https://github.com/dshkwnds/google-diff-match-patch) (it is available for both [C#](https://github.com/dshkwnds/google-diff-match-patch/tree/master/csharp) and [Python](https://github.com/dshkwnds/google-diff-match-patch/tree/master/python3))
- compare extracted images using histograms or even some simple way like [this one based on pixels comparision](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/domgreen/archive/2009/09/06/comparing-two-images-in-c.aspx)
- Tables are not separate objects in PDF but just text objects + lines (or even just a background image with a grid). If you are looking to work with tables  then you may be interested to check paid [PDF Extractor SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) from ByteScout or open-source [Tabula-extractor](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor) project which are both capable of detecting and extracting tables.

*Disclosure: I'm affiliated with ByteScout*

Comment: I was able to extract the text using iTextSharp. I created an object that holds the text, Rectangle coordinates surrounding it and page number it was found on so I could later go back into the PDF and highlight any differences. I pull all the text from the list of my objects and call the google-diff-match-patch function and get all the correct differences. Now I am stuck on mapping the results back to my objects to highlight at the correct locations.

Comment: The results of the google-diff-patch-match function are broken up for example if the dates in the PDFS were different, December and January would return <DELETE, 'Decembe'> and <EQUAL, 'r'> and <INSERT, 'Janua'> <INSERT, 'y'>.

Comment: Yes, this is the way it works, symbol by symbol. You may decrease the sensitivity by setting Efficiency Cleanup to 8 (default is 4). Also you may want to check DiffPlex as well (it is for c# only), it compares line by line https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex